# How to test nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a game model that has some releases (has_many). I've chosen to use nested resources to express this.

```
resources :games do
  resources :releases, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
 end
```

I'm trying to use RSpec to test my release controller actions. Here is a part of my test file.

```
 describe "GET new" do
  it "assigns a new release as @release" do
    get :new, {}, valid_session
    assigns(:release).should be_a_new(Release)
  end
 end
```

When I don't set game_id parameter I have a No Routes Match error. And when I add `:game_id => 1` I have a RecordNotFound error.

So my question is how can I set a game object to express the nested resource ?

Comment: This should work but I think you'd need to create a 'game' first - we do this with factorygirl but you don't need to. S

Comment: Thanks, to be honest, I'm not very familiar with testing, rspec, and factorygirl. Could you post an example if you have one ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to rspec too - be gentle :) Once you get into testing your apps properly, your life will be faster, better and less stressful. Your applications will benefit even more and so will your customers.

After a month or so, I don't use the browser until I need to style my pages. Faster and more efficient.

Personally, I started reading through this tutorial:

- http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html

And also, as ever, the following RailsCasts helped enormously:

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test
- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures

In your case, try something like this (without FactoryGirl).

```
describe "GET new" do
 it "assigns a new release as @release" do
   game = Game.create!( << INSERT VALID ATTRIBUTE >> )
   get :new, {:game_id => game.id}, valid_session
   assigns(:release).should be_a_new(Release)
 end
end
```

I think that's right, haven't tested myself. There's a few other ways you could do it including put the game creation method is a before filter:

```
 before(:each) do
   @game = Game.create!( << INSERT VALID ATTRIBUTE >> )
 end
```

Or, like I said, using Factory Girl to build the model for you.

This is how we do it.